Azure SQL trigger takes 36 times longer when surpassing 6200 rows
I have created a trigger that is supposed to update a table (clients_kv) with a foreign key on updates in the table regions_kv. To avoid updating for all values in regions_kv, I'm doing some extra joins over inserted and regions_kv.
The stored procedure CleanupOldRecords just selects the latest value per identifier in regions_kv. My problem is that the trigger works fine (round 30 seconds) when inserting up to 6200 rows but when reaching 6300 rows, it runs for 18 minutes.
The update part works fine outside the trigger. If I remove the CASE WHEN part in the update statement, it also works. If I remove the extra joins over inserted, it also works. I have doubled the DTU's in Azure without any difference. If i run it in two batches (i.e. initiate the trigger for each batch), the first batch of size 3000, and second of size 3600 it runs in around a total of 30 seconds. I have not created any indexes as of yet.
When looking at Query Performance Insights in Azure, the update steps duration is a few seconds shorter than the entire query of 18 minutes. CPU or DATA IO never exceed 30% and 2% respectively.
Most important is  to understand why this exponential increase in duration happens.
Any help or pointing in the right direction is very appreciated!
CREATE TRIGGER trg_instead_of_insert_regions_kv
ON dbo.regions_kv
-- instead of insert lets the user define how data is inserted
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Create a temporary table to hold distinct newValue_id values
    CREATE TABLE #AffectedValueIds
    (
        newValue_id INT
    );

    -- Insert distinct newValue_id values from the `inserted` rows into the temporary table
    INSERT INTO #AffectedValueIds (newValue_id)
        SELECT DISTINCT newValue_id
        FROM inserted;

    -- Insert the new rows into the target table
    INSERT INTO dbo.regions_kv
        SELECT *
        FROM inserted;

    -- Call the stored procedure to perform cleanup, referencing #AffectedValueIds
    EXEC dbo.CleanupOldRecords @SchemaName = 'dbo', @TableName = 'regions_kv';

    -- Insert the new rows into the target table and create a new forreign key
    UPDATE cl
    SET fk_regional_council_id = 
          CASE 
            WHEN r1.newValue_type = 'REGION_TYPE_REGIONAL_COUNCIL' THEN r1.newValue_id
            WHEN r2.newValue_type = 'REGION_TYPE_REGIONAL_COUNCIL' THEN r2.newValue_id
            WHEN r3.newValue_type = 'REGION_TYPE_REGIONAL_COUNCIL' THEN r3.newValue_id
        ELSE NULL 
        END, 
        fk_region_id = COALESCE(r1.newValue_id, r2.newValue_id, r3.newValue_id)
    FROM dbo.clients_kv as cl
    INNER JOIN inserted as i
    ON cl.newValue_operationalRegionIds = i.newValue_id
    -- we only want the cleaned observations from inserted
    INNER JOIN regions_kv r0 ON r0.header_eventId = i.header_eventId
    INNER JOIN regions_kv r1 ON r1.newValue_id = cl.newValue_operationalRegionIds
    LEFT JOIN regions_kv r2 ON r2.newValue_id = r1.newValue_parentRegionId
    LEFT JOIN regions_kv r3 ON r3.newValue_id = r2.newValue_parentRegionId

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END;


Could you try process those rows in batches?
DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 100;
DECLARE @RowCount INT;
DECLARE @Offset INT = 0;

-- Process rows in batches
SELECT @RowCount = COUNT(*) FROM #AffectedValueIds;

WHILE @Offset < @RowCount
BEGIN
-- Insert the new rows into the target table
INSERT INTO dbo.regions_kv
SELECT *
FROM inserted
ORDER BY newValue_id
OFFSET @Offset ROWS FETCH NEXT @BatchSize ROWS ONLY;

-- Rest of the code here

SET @Offset = @Offset + @BatchSize;
END

In addition, please ensure that the columns used in joins and the CASE expression are properly indexed.
Have you look at the Azure SQL Database Query Performance Insight? Is this T-SQL code identified as a top CPU or IO bottleneck?

I have now updated the question with regard to indexes and Azure Query Performance Insights.
I ran your query but it still takes very long time. If I instead trigger the trigger with batches of round 3000, it runs much faster, round 30 seconds in total.

We should design triggers to be lightweight. Long-running queries that can hold locks for extended periods may create blocking.

Agree. It's supposed to only handle a couple of observations once data is loaded. Its during the initial loading that this happens. I rewrote the query as it didn't make any sense for other reasons and now it runs as expected. Still curious though as to why the update step takes so long inside the trigger and not outside? Maybe SQL moves in mysterious ways and you have to live with it..

There are many things that can be causing this for example, throttling may be behind what you experienced. Premium tiers use local attached SSD, upper level Standard tiers use remote SSD, and lower level Standard tiers use mechanic hard drives.
